MMSE estimator of Gaussian mixture
I'm trying to find the MMSE estimator of the Gaussian mixture with a linear Gaussian noise channel. Specifically, we have

$p(x)=\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$,
$p(y|x) = \mathcal{N}(ax,\sigma_0^2)$, i.e., $y=ax+\sigma_0z$, where $z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

When I attempt to find the MMSE estimator (i.e., $\mathbb{E}_{p(x|y)}[x]$), I first compute the posterior $p(x|y)$:
\begin{align*}
p(x|y) = \frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{p(y)}=\frac{1}{p(y)}p(y|x)\Big(\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)\Big).
\end{align*}
For each component of $x$ (e.g., $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$), since $p(y|x)$ is also Gaussian, the posterior for each component is Gaussian (e.g., $\mathcal{N}\Big(\frac{\frac{ay}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}},~\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}}\Big)$). Thus, the overall distribution will be a Gaussian mixture with
\begin{align*}
p(x|y) = \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}\Big(\frac{\frac{ay}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}},~\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}}\Big) + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{N}\Big(\frac{\frac{ay}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_2}{\sigma_2^2}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}}, ~\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}}\Big).
\end{align*}
And the MMSE estimator would be $\mathbb{E}_{p(x|y)}[x]=\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{aY}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2}\big)/\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{aY}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_2}{\sigma_2^2}\big)/\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}\big)$.
But I think the result is weird. Say, if we set $\mu_1=1$, $\mu_2=-1$, $a=1$, and we get a noisy sample $y=1.5$, intuitively it is more likely that the original $x$ is sampled from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ instead of $\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. So, should the estimation from the first component be given more weight? For example, something like $0.8\big(\frac{aY}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_1}{\sigma_1^2}\big)/\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}\big)+0.2\big(\frac{aY}{\sigma_0^2}+\frac{\mu_2}{\sigma_2^2}\big)/\big(\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}\big)$?
Do I misunderstand something, or is my attempt at the MMSE wrong? Thanks in advance for any comments.

We cannot talk about which component is more likely without further considering the relative sizes of $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$. In your example, if $\sigma_0^2,\sigma_1^2\rightarrow 0^+$ but $\sigma_2^2$ is large, it could be more likely for the realized $x$ to come from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$.

EDIT: However, the distribution of $X\mid Y$ is mixed by posterior proportions than prior proportions.
It might be helpful to rewrite the mixture model as
$$\left\lbrace \begin{align}Y\mid X &\sim\mathcal{N}(a x, \sigma_0^2) \\
X\mid Z &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Z, \sigma_Z^2)\\
Z&=i\text{ with probability }p_i
\end{align}\right.$$
for $0<p_1<1$ and $p_2=1-p_1$.
The question of which component $X$ arose from is answered by
$$
f_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y)=\sum_{i=1}^2 \tilde{p}_i I(z=i)
$$
where the posterior probability $\tilde{p}_i$ is given by
$$
\tilde{p}_i = \frac{d_i p_i}{\sum_{j=1}^2 d_j p_j}
$$
with
$$d_i=\phi\left(y;\ a\mu_i,\ a^2\sigma_i^2+\sigma_0^2\right)$$
and $\phi(\cdot\,;\ \mu,\ \sigma^2)$ denotes the density of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.
The density of $X\mid Y$ is
$$\begin{align}
f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) &=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^2  \phi(y;\ ax,\sigma_0^2)\phi(x;\ \mu_i,\sigma_i^2) \cdot p_i}{\sum_{j=1}^2d_jp_j} \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^2  \frac{\phi(y;\ ax,\sigma_0^2)\phi(x;\ \mu_i,\sigma_i^2)}{d_i} \cdot \tilde{p}_i \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^2 \phi(x;\ \tilde{\mu}_i,\tilde{\sigma}_i^2)  \tilde{p}_i
\end{align}
$$
where, as derived in the OP,
$$\tilde\sigma_i^2=\frac1{\frac1{\sigma_i^2}+\frac{a^2}{\sigma_0^2}}\text{ and }
\tilde\mu_i=\tilde\sigma_i^2\left(\frac{\mu_i}{\sigma_i^2}+\frac{ay}{\sigma_0^2}\right).
$$

Thanks for your answer. But if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=1$ in the case, given the information $y=1.5$, I think still $x$ more likely comes from $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$. Should the estimation from the first component be given more weight? Current $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ does take care of the variance, but how about the weights between two components?

@Harry556 You are right. The distribution of $X∣Y$  has different mixing proportions than $1/2$. It should be mixed by posterior probabilities. I just edited my answer.

Thanks! I just derive the same results. And there is a paper in which a more general case is considered. Thanks for your answer anyway.
